# While body is not me or mine what is a wise response to those claiming various degrees of ownerships on body?

Tags: ethics, society

What are some kind, wholesome, skillful, wise and helpful responses and views to the following various claims of body ownership:

“The United States government claims 100% ownership over all your DNA and reproductive rights. This astonishing revelation has emerged from the fact that the U.S. Patent and Trademark Office claims the power to assign ownership of your DNA to private companies and universities who apply for patents on your genes.

To date, more than 4,000 genes have been assigned ownership to corporations and universities by the U.S. patent office. Such an assignment of ownership proves that the government believes it owns 100% of all human genes -- you cannot transfer ownership of something unless you first own it yourself.

To date, 20 percent of your genetic code is owned by someone else. About two-thirds of these patents belong to private companies, and one-third belong to universities. The company that owns the most patents is called Incyte, a drug company based in California which "owns" the patents on 2,000 human genes.” Via https://www.naturalnews.com/040400_gene_patents_genetic_slavery_human_DNA.html

And from 2012 via http://anh-usa.org/fda-new-claim-body-is-a-drug/ :

...[The] FDA says your own stem cells are drugs—and stem cell therapy is interstate commerce because it affects the bottom line of FDA-approved drugs in other states!

We wish this were a joke, but it’s the US Food and Drug Administration’s latest claim in its battle with a Colorado clinic over its Regenexx-C™ procedure, a non-surgical treatment for people suffering from moderate to severe joint or bone pain using adult stem cells.

The FDA asserts in a court document that it has the right to regulate the Centeno-Schultz Medical Clinic for two reasons:

1) Stem cells are drugs and therefore fall within their jurisdiction. (The clinic argues that stem cell therapy is the practice of medicine and is therefore not within the FDA’s jurisdiction!)

2) The clinic is engaging in interstate commerce and is therefore subject to FDA regulation because any part of the machine or procedure that originates outside Colorado becomes interstate commerce once it enters the state. Moreover, interstate commerce is substantially affected because individuals traveling to Colorado to have the Regenexx procedure would “depress the market for out-of-state drugs that are approved by FDA.”

[note: full articles linked here link to source documents]

Comment: If the building & coming totalitarianism can be discerned, this is a cause for developing disenchantment towards the whole world, as the Buddha taught. Like they did in Russia in 1917, these asura can rip you to shreds. Thus, the requisite Dhamma is the refuge of abandoning self-view.

Comment: The government could put the human body in prison too, or tax it, or kill it, assign it a birth certificate and a nationality, and so on. But what is the question here -- what is the question about Buddhism? There's no question mark in the body of the text. The title is asking "how about other claims?" and I don't understand what that means -- what is that asking?

Comment: It, the householders question, is asking whether any kind of sakkāyadiṭṭhi is worthwhile to hold on, and if which, of which is not a foolish and unclear question at all, althought the sample might lead easy astray between those holding on "on-group-holding-identification". Sangha, group of those headed to go beyound, vatta (tradition), the boot, body, is importand to hold on to be able to cross.

Comment: rephrased the question header and posed a question in the body. please notify if still not up to snuff and/or if the question becomes open ((or un-closed) if the automated system doesn't do a tray notification then delete this comment please)

Comment: Maybe taking the sample away and ask generally, in what way it is healthy to see "ones" body as ones own or others identification as owned by them.

Comment: I'm still don't understand what the question is -- "What is a wise response?" -- I guess an example of a "response" might be, like, writing a letter to the US government or something, to the US patent office or to the FDA. But surely you're not asking what to put in that letter ... so what are you asking? I can just about see how copyright law affects the publishing of dhamma, I don't see what this (i.e. FDA's regulation of medicines, and its use of the US courts) has to do with "Buddhist doctrine or practice".

Comment: Hey Chris. Imagine government officials or prominent celebrity social activists seeking advice from a Buddhist worldview on these social issues. There's an answer and several comments addressing this question so it seems some have had some kind of understanding pertaining to this question. Thanks for your time and consideration

Comment: Can you edit it to make it clearer? I read what you posted as saying, "I read this article which says that the government does this thing, which is scandalous" -- but that's not a question, and it seems like more to do with law or politics than Buddhism.

Comment: I can definitely see how this question can easily be upsetting and controversial. It seems there are no clear immediate responses so it is understandable that folks could get freaked out about it at least until maybe a Buddhist authority weighs in on it because it seems many folks want someone else to do their thinking and then be able to agree or disagree with it. (Including me on this topic. Ha.) May sit with this and get back to it. Who knows.

Comment: Bhante Sujato weighed in on this topic [on minute mp3]: https://integratingpresence.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/on-genetic-ownership-attempts-day-1-cloud-recording-vesak-poya-week-life-of-the-buddha-by-ajahn-sujato-28th-may.mp3

Answer (score 0):

The body is considered not mine since one cannot maintain it as one wisher. The fact that others may store certain genetic information without one's liking is a good example that the body is not completely in one's control, hence not-self/non-self.

Comment: Imho a wise reply to someone expressing aclaimof ownership is a good old; 'but to what extent is it ownership and why it is called ownership?. More often than not i imagine that the ownership there is a reference to the judical system and relative rights and agreements